# Building flutter apk

Tags: flutter

when I am trying to build apk with flutter build apk command I am getting this error Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code 9.plz help me to resolve this.my flutter version is Flutter 1.20.1 and dart version is version: 2.9.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please upgrade to latest master and try agian?
Execute following
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
flutter doctor -v
and trying the building appbundle again

Comment: thank you so much it is working. can you suggest me something actually I want to use design pattern for my flutter app like block pattern,mvc,mvvm or provider.which one I should use.

Comment: provider is best and also recommended by flutter team and its easy to use and easy to learn.